# cake smells bad of egg, is dense and rubbery

Tags: baking, eggs, cake, smell, sponge-cake

This was the first time bake a cake (basic sponge cake) with an electric beater. The final result was that the cake was smelling very bad of eggs, it was was very dense and rubbery.

I dont see this kind of cake  in bakery, there the cakes are fluffy, soft and dontsmell of eggs. what is that they use in bakery. or what could have gone wrong in making my cake.

This is the link which I followed to make the cake:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HF7BlcIGNyo&t=96s

I did exactly as shown  in the video.

I put:

3 eggs,
1 cup flour,
1 cup all purpose flour,
1/2 tea spoon baking powder,
few drops vanilla essence,
1 cup sugar,
1 table spoon butter,
few drops of milk.

I made the batter this way:
I separated the egg yolks and egg whites, and whipped the egg whites untill it became like foam an it aside .Then I started beating the egg yolks with vanilla essence,butter, milk and sugar in batches and set aside. I mixed baking powder in the flour. Then I mixed then egg yolks in the egg whites. Then I mixed flour in the batter.
I preheated the oven at 160 degree for 1 minute. Then for 20 minutes I baked the caked at 200C.

Please help! :(

Comment: Without knowing the recipe you followed and the method, it is difficult for us to advise you. Please add this info by editing your question and explain if you followed the directions exactly or not. If not, explain what you did differently.

Comment: Pls improve further, describe HOW you built your batter from these.

Comment: Would you like to [merge your accounts](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)?

Answer (score 2):

For any specific answer, the recipe and if possible pictures would help, but I will try a general idea which comes to mind.  If your cake smells like eggs, it is eggs. To me this would mean inadequate aeration of the eggs and mixing with the dry ingredients.  A dense, flat, rubbery cake again would be an indication of the same.  If it is also wet, under cooking may compound it.

The sponge I make calls for yolk and whites to be separated.  Yolks are then beaten to a ribbon state and whites to at least soft peak.  Yolks are used to make a batter and the whites are then very gently folded in.  This aerates the eggs enough that as long as there is not a delay before baking it is almost impossible for the cake to not rise and be soft from the expanding of air trapped in the egg.  Not having this air in the eggs would result in baked eggs with a bit of flour added.

ETA:  I would suggest online "Joy of Baking", look up their videos on sponge cakes.  You do not need follow their recipe if you have one you would rather, but they tend to do a good job showing the proper level to beat the eggs for a ribbon and folding in egg whites without collapsing the foam.